# How do I keep a child(position:fixed) below the parent(`position:fixed`)?

Tags: html, css

How do I place a child element (with `position:fixed`) below the parent element(with `position:fixed`). I tried giving a lower z-index to child element than the z-index value of parent element. But it is still on top of the parent element. Can't I make it appear below the parent using lower z-index ?

How do I do it ?

Comment: position fixed is relative to the viewport so there is no need for the  child element to be fixed as well - make child div absolute to the parent div (it should remain fixed to the view port as the parent shouldn't move).  However as the element is a child of the parent, you will never get this below the parent - you will need to seperate them if you want the inner div under the outer div

Comment: @Pete: `"there is no need for it to be a child element of another fixed position element"` - Actually this is a part of hack for I need to show the element1(child) only when element2(parent) is visible

Comment: you're probably better of using javascript for that then (I also edited the comment as I realised that wasn't true!)

Comment: ok.. I wasn't sure I 'll get a solution, just wanted if there is one! last resort javascript now!

Answer (score 0):

As far as know, the z-index is inside the parent, hence child object can't be under it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/VD9Dv/ . Two different combinations of divs will show you the difference.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>  

    <div class="parent positioned">   
    </div>
     <div class="child positioned"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{width:200px;height:200px;background:#ccc;
 position:fixed;z-index:100;padding:15px}
.child{width:100px;height:100px;background:#eeffcc;
 position:fixed;z-index:-90}

.positioned{
    left: 240px;
}
```

Comment: I wanted the child to be below parent. I think this isn't meant as  a solution for my case ?

Comment: ya the second one should be your solution. It shows the child div(not actually child) under the parent.

Comment: I meant parent child relationship to be real, not just naming classes such.. :) Unfortunately this won't work for me.. :(

Comment: Ok, with the fixed position it will not work how you want it. best of luck. If you find a solution post it here for others help.

Comment: I couldn't found a css solution. Now I would just use javascript instead.